# Do I have to start some kind of sqlite server before using it in android application

Tags: android, sqlite

well, almost everything is in the question, I have a problem with program which should use the sqlite, it still returns the "unexpected error", I was just wondering do I have to start some kind of server, deamon or service?

androidManifest[ snippet ]

```
<activity android:name=".About">
android:label="@string/about_title" 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Exit">
andorid:label="@string/exit_title">    
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Options">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Start">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Create">
</activity>

</application>
```

AndroidSQLite

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.sql);
TextView listContent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);
mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
mySQLiteAdapter.deleteAll();
mySQLiteAdapter.insert("ABCDE");
mySQLiteAdapter.insert("FGHIJK");
mySQLiteAdapter.insert("1234567");
mySQLiteAdapter.insert("890");
mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Testing");
mySQLiteAdapter.close();
mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();
String contentRead = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
mySQLiteAdapter.close();
listContent.setText(contentRead);
}
```

sql.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/app_name"
/>
<ListView
android:id="@+id/contentlist"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

main.xml [snippet]

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/where_button"
android:onClick="WhereCl"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/where_label" />
```

code responsible for button Where Am I?

mainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

View startButton = findViewById(R.id.start_button);
View whereButton = findViewById(R.id.where_button);
View aboutButton = findViewById(R.id.about_button);
View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit_button);

}

public void OptionsCl(View v){

startActivity(new Intent(this,Options.class));
}

public void WhereCl(View v){

startActivity(new Intent(this,AndroidSQLite.class));
}

public void StartCl(View v){

Intent idd = new Intent(this,Start.class);
startActivity(idd);
}
public void AboutCl(View v){

startActivity(new Intent(this,About.class));
}
public void ExitCl(View v){

finish();
}

}
```

the error I receive is similar to this which come up with unregistred action, but the action is registred [ check the code ]

it is just "the application blabla (menu.dot) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again" Force close.

Comment: No, SQLite is file based anyway, so ready to use with the given library. You better post your table schema and query and we can tell you what is wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Android SQLite is readymade library**. So you don't need to start any Service, server or demon. Just to initiate a database class extending SQLite DatabaseHelper class and use it.

Thanks.